# SQL Server Import Job Removed Data After Job Failed

Tags: sql-server, import

I have a SQL Server Job set up to import data from a table to a table on another server, using the Import/Export data wizard.

In one instance, the job failed (with, I believe a SQL connection issue), and with that, the data from *both* tables were deleted. The tables on both the source and destination server were removed.

Does this make sense? If anything, why would the data be removed from the *source*?

The source is SQL Server 2012 and the destination is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed with this import job was the security option was something other than the default, "encrypt sensitive data with user key". After changing it back to the default, I didn't have this problem again (so far).

Now, how and why that would cause this behavior, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the control flow, both in your SQL Agent job, and the SSIS package it's running. I suspect there's a step in one of them that cleans out the source table after the work is finished, and this step is running regardless of whether the import succeeded or not.

Or there may be an unrelated cleanup job that cleans out that import table.

Comment: I don't know of any cleanup job. And if that would be the case, the table would be cleared each time it's ran, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> In one instance, the job failed (with, I believe a SQL connection issue), and with that, the data from both tables were deleted. The tables on both the source and destination server were removed.
>
> Does this make sense? If anything, why would the data be removed from the source?

No this does not make sense, unless you have selected it to delete destination data when creating SSIS package using Import/Export Wizard.

You must have selected :

[Delete rows in an existing destination table.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) - See step 3 in BOL.

[image]

The same might be selected for source tables.

Check the package, you will find the incorrect setting.

Comment: Sure I had the delete rows checked off. But that doesn't explain why the data in the *source* table was deleted.

Comment: @Rivka Look in the sql agent job as well as the package itself, there should be as there is no way that SQL Server will decide to purge your data unless IT is instructed (delete or truncate). If you are still not able to find out, then there might be a rouge process -- fire up a sql trace to see whats going on the database server.